# Pass parameter to callback in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have these two methods in my application controller what i want is to use them as callbacks in my projects_controller like this but it gives me error, can anyone tell me how to fix this.

```
before_action :permit_show(@project), only:[:show]
before_action :permit_edit(@project), only:[:edit]



def permit_edit(object)
  if (current_user.id != object.creator_id)
   render_404
  end   
end

def permit_show(object)
 members = object.users
 if (!members.include? current_user)
  render_404
 end   
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass in parameters, you have to use a block.

```
before_filter(only: [:show]) { permit_show(@project) }
before_filter(only: [:edit]) { permit_edit(@project) }
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass then that block into skip_before_action to skip that callback?

Answer (score 1):

You can use send method to pass parameter something like this -

```
before_action only: [:show] do |c|
  c.send(:permit_show, @project)
end

before_action only: [:edit] do |c|
   c.send(:permit_edit, @project)
end
```

Comment: You don't need send in this case, just `permit_edit(@project)` should work too.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30222518/600953).

---

...you can achieve what you're looking for by using optional method parameters, like so:

```
def cache_bust(callback = true)
  ... method body
end
```

In the scenario where the method is called from the after_update callback, the parameter is not passed, but defaults to true. Otherwise, if the method is called from anywhere else "manually", you have the option of passing whatever value you wish to that method.