# Rails pass params/arguments to ActiveRecord callback function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the snippet below in one of my AR models:

```
after_update :cache_bust
```

The `cache_bust` method in the model accepts a parameter (boolean) that sets the value of itself to `false` by default.

How can I pass `true` to this method in the model from my ActiveRecord callback defined above it?

Ex: `after_update :cache_bust(true)` does not work because it's a symbol, how can I pass `true` to the method's param?

Comment: What determines the boolean value?

Comment: I want to pass through true if it's called via the callback, and not pass through anything if called elsewhere.  I tried using Ruby's `caller` but it returns the same thing.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> There are four types of callbacks accepted by the callback macros: Method references (symbol), callback objects, inline methods (using a proc), and inline eval methods (using a string).

Try this?

```
after_update -> { cache_bust(true) }
```

Comment: Worked, switched my answer acceptance as this solves the problem and the other answer is an alternative.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your clarification, you can achieve what you're looking for by using optional method parameters, like so:

```
def cache_bust(callback = true)
    ... method body
end
```

In the scenario where the method is called from the `after_update` callback, the parameter is not passed, but defaults to true. Otherwise, if the method is called from anywhere else "manually", you have the option of passing whatever value you wish to that method.

Comment: This answers the actual question which is what I was searching on google.

Answer (score -3):

Very easy to pass params from controller to callback, you can call name of params in model. Example:

In controller:

```
Quiz.create(name: 'abc')
```

In model:

```
before_create :valid_name?

def valid_name?
  puts name
end
```

Comment: This did not work for me in Rails 5 when calling `create` outside of the controller.

Answer (score -5):

Short answer is No.You cannot pass any arguments.
You could use attr_accessor to create a virtual attribute and set that attribute.

Comment: This might be a good idea, but you need to provide a more detailed step by step explanation with a code example.